# How to install cinder-volume service when OpenStack installed using MicroStack

Tags: openstack, openstack-cinder, microstack

How can I install cinder-volume as only cinder-scheduler will be installed in microstack deployment. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc84i.png

Comment: As far as I understand it, Cinder is [installed automatically](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/microstack-get-started#1-overview): "MicroStack includes all key OpenStack components: Keystone, Nova, Neutron, Glance, and Cinder". This includes cinder-volume.

Comment: When we go service by service installation then for `#openstack volume service list` will give us cinder-scheduler and cinder-volume but in microstack Deployment only scheduler is there. Even volumes can't be created in this kind scenarios. Only the instances without volume can be created.

Comment: I got around installing Microstack right now because this question interests me. It configures OpenStack in an extremely weird way; nothing is where I expect it to be. I don't have cinder-volume either, and what's weirder, there is no Cinder log file (it should be /var/snap/microstack/common/log/cinder.log, but this file doesn't exist).

Comment: [This here](https://microstack.run/docs) contradicts my first comment: "Supported services are currently Glance, Horizon, Keystone, Neutron, and Nova". Nothing about Cinder.

Comment: Do you have any idea how we can edit Horizon in Microstack Deployment ?

Comment: Even less than how to fix Cinder.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo microstack init --auto --control --setup-loop-based-cinder-lvm-backend --loop-device-file-size 50
```

Read more:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/microstack/+bug/1928781